# Watir Submit :tag_name=>"button" not found

Tags: click, submit, watir

I am stomped by a simple click command for the following fragment

```
<TR>  
    <TD>  
       <P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Send" VALUE="SEND">  
       <INPUT TYPE="RESET" NAME="Clear" VALUE="Clear">
    </TD>  
</TR>
```

The following watir line does not seem to work

```
browser.button(:name=>'Send').click
```

I get 
``` /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:365:in ``assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:name=>"Send", :tag_name=>"button"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException) ```

have tried different combination of :name and :value.

Comment: this is the site. only a few lines http://msg.koodomobile.com/msg/1.1/in_sendatextmessage.html

Answer (score 5):

I believe this problem is related to the case sensitivity problem described in [Watir-Webdriver Issue 72](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/72). Basically because the button has `TYPE="SUBMIT"`, it is not found since watir is looking for "submit" (note the case difference).

As a workaround, you can do:

```
#Using input type
browser.input(:name => 'Send').click

#Using css locator
browser.element(:css => 'input[type=submit][name=Send]').click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.button(type: "submit").click
```

Answer (score -3):

what about this---
       browser.button(:name, "Send").click

Comment: This is completely the same as in the questions.

Comment: watir can't seem to find the element whether I used :value or :name. I have also used .element as suggested in other posts.